# Visual Studio Code debugs even when i run without debugging

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

i just installed VSCode and I used to work on it

but now when I try to 'run without Debugging' with 'Ctrl + F5'.

it seems to opens up 'python debug console' and debug like below image

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ws9r6.png)

i was expecting powershell or cmd (defulat terminal) to open without debugging but it doesn't work that way.

Comment: have you timed the run time of `F5` and `Ctrl+F5`, the commands look the same but it executes faster

Comment: you don't see any difference in execution time for 1 line print statements, do some heavy calculation and you notice the difference

Comment: the program will not stop on any breakpoint set with `Ctrl+F5` and it runs faster

Comment: May I know what's going on with the problem? If it has been solved, can you change the status of the answer to help more people with similar problems.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a problem. Whether it is `F5` or `Ctrl+F5`, the debugger will be used, and the configuration in *launch.json* will be used. The difference between the two is that one can debug, and the other is not. If you set a breakpoint in the code, the former will stop and the latter will not.

[image]

If you want to run the script directly instead of debugging, use the triangle button in the upper right corner.

[image]