# python VSCode: suggested way to run code differently based on launch / debug state

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I've got some python code which iterates over a large number of files, and I've written a simple multithread pool, which speeds it up substantially.  (The app is not remotely complex, there are no concurrency or locking issues as each input file is mapped 1:1 to an output file and there are no shared data structures across these threads...)

However, when I'm debugging (in VSCode), it's far easier on me to run it as a single thread so I added a variable to the function call that allows me to force it to run without threads.  This solves the problem but is manual and clunky.  I've thought of at least a couple of ways I could semi-automate this, but knowing very little about this stuff (obviously) I figured I'd ask for suggestions.

1. I could set an environment variable, pull that into the script, and then based on that variable choose the single vs multi-threaded code.
2. I could add an argument to the existing parser that selects single/multi threaded mode.

If either of these exist, I could presumably modify the `launch.json` stanzas for the debugger and have it set those arguments or variables before it launches the code in the debugger.

BUT, and this part I'm confused on... does the Ctrl-F5 "run program" shortcut always execute exactly the same as the "F5" shortcut that launches the program inside the debugger?

I very often use Ctrl-F5 when I know (or at least think!) that the code will run, whereas I use F5 when I think it won't.  Is there some reasonable way to have Ctrl-F5 do something "very slightly different" than just F5?

It's also entirely possible that what I've just described is a *Very Bad Idea* for reasons that are not obvious to me, and/or that there is much more elegant and unknown-to-me wisdom in this matter...  ;-)

Answer (score 0):

> does the Ctrl-F5 "run program" shortcut always execute exactly the same as the "F5" shortcut that launches the program inside the debugger?

Both use the debugger to execute the code, and both will also use the configuration in launch.json. The difference is that **F5** will stop at the breakpoint and **Ctrl+F5** will not.

[image]

*https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/debugging#_run-mode*

If you want to run the script directly:

[image]

Comment: this is essentially a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/77458146/11107541 ...